# pygame event AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'MOUSEBUTTONUP'

Tags: python

I was following a tutorial on simulating physics with pymunk and pygame, however when i got to the part using `event.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`, it keeps being highlighted by pycharm and says "':' expected". Changing it from = to == fixed this issue but now whenever it runs it gives the error.

```
if event.type == event.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    pps.append(create_pp(space,event.pos))
```

> AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'MOUSEBUTTONUP'

```
import pygame,sys,pymunk

def create_pp(space,pos):
    body = pymunk.Body(1,100,body_type = pymunk.Body.DYNAMIC)
    body.position = pos
    shape = pymunk.Circle(body,80)
    space.add(body,shape)
    return shape

def draw_pps(pps):
    for pp in pps:
        pos_x = int(pp.body.position.x)
        pos_y = int(pp.body.position.y)
        pp_rect = pp_surface.get_rect(center = (pos_x,pos_y))
        screen.blit(pp_surface,pp_rect)

def static_mouth(space):
    body = pymunk.Body(body_type = pymunk.Body.STATIC)
    body.position = (430,400)
    shape = pymunk.Circle(body, 50)
    space.add(body,shape)
    return shape

def draw_static_mouth(mouths):
    for mouth in mouths:
        pos_x = int(mouth.body.position.x)
        pos_y = int(mouth.body.position.y)
        mouth_rect = mouth_surface.get_rect(center = (pos_x,pos_y))
        screen.blit(mouth_surface, mouth_rect)

pygame.init() #initiating pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600)) #creates display surface
clock = pygame.time.Clock() #creating game clock
space = pymunk.Space()
space.gravity = (0,400)
pp_surface = pygame.image.load('Drawing.png')
mouth_surface = pygame.image.load('Mouth.png')
pps = []

mouths = []
mouths.append(static_mouth(space))
while True: #game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get(): #checks for user input
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == event.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pps.append(create_pp(space,event.pos))

    screen.fill((217,217,217)) #backgroun color
    draw_pps(pps)
    draw_static_mouth(mouths)
    space.step(1/50)
    pygame.display.update() #renders frame
    clock.tick(120) #limiting fps to 120
```

Answer (score 1):

I think is this part went wrong `if event.type == event.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:`

I think u could try this

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
```